# React Maximum call stack size exceeded when using react-hot-loader

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

When using `react-hot-loader`,a strange issue occurs to me.

Only this case will throw `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at PatientEdit.__test__REACT_HOT_LOADER__`

```
class PatientEdit extends React.Component {
    test = () => {
        return 123
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    static propTypes = {
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.test()}</div>)
    }
}
```

But the followings three are all right

```
// A
class PatientEdit extends React.Component {
    test(){
        return 123
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    static propTypes = {}
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.test()}</div>)
    }
}
// B
class PatientEdit extends React.Component {
    test(){
        return 123
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    static propTypes = {}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.test()}</div>)
    }
}
// C
class PatientEdit extends React.Component {
    test = () => {
        return 123
    }
    static propTypes = {}
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.test()}</div>)
    }
}
```

Loader configuration  was followed as the doc says : `.babelrc` as below, add `babel-polyfill` and `react-hot-loader/patch` before file entry

```
    // .babelrc
    {
        "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react", "stage-1"],
        "plugins": [
            "react-hot-loader/babel",
            "transform-decorators-legacy",
            "transform-flow-strip-types",
            "transform-object-assign",
            "transform-runtime",
            "typecheck",
            "react-css-modules"
        ]
    }
```

In the beginning i was too shocked by the strange behavior and ignored the error stack. Now its my time to look into `react-hot-loader`'s mechanism and welcome detailed explainations

Comment: So `A` and `B` works, but not `C`?

Comment: Have you tried this.test.bind(this) ?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with your current code. Are you sure you are not doing anything else in the test function which causes re-rendering

Comment: Working without any error : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-max-call-stack

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri @ Vivek Doshi  sry, i was too concerned about the weird. It turns out to be as a result of `react-hot-loader/babel` and i will add more details

Comment: @Chris see the edited question

Comment: @rrd Your consideration is case A and its fine. see the edited question

Comment: Put the constructor first, more related to @jankoritak 's answer below ofc.

Comment: @rrd arrow function binding issue is obvious. Know how to do it without error and  just curious about the detailed reason .

Answer (score 1):

More of a guess than true reasoning. (Would love to hear throughout answer though)

Arrow function auto-binds itself to it's runtime context. (In this case PatientEdit class instance, resp. component).

I'm guessing the problem is, the class instance hasn't been created yet, as constructor has not been executed. But the instance is needed to be bound to. This probably causes class code to run again (in expectation to find it's constructor). And this is what causes the loop which, in the end, results with call stack overflow.